# Python - How to use the function's old result while waiting for its new result

Tags: python, multithreading, function, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

Let's say I have 2 functions like this:

- Function 1: To Calculate a. And it takes 5 hours to return the result of a for each calculation.

```py
def Calculate_a (x,y,z,t)
    Do_somthing_to_calculate_a
    return a
```

- Function 2: Calculate the sum of a + b (b is any number). The requirement is that Function 2 must produce results every 5 seconds or less.

```py
def Sum(a, b):
    s = a + b
    return s

a = Calculate_a (x,y,z,t) #a is the return result of Function 1
s = Sum(a, b)
print(s)
```

The question is: How can I print out "result s" every 5s.

If I pass parameter a as usual, Function 2 has to wait for Function 1 to finish calculating (I have to wait 5 hours). Thus, I will not be able to get the result of Function 1 every 5 seconds.

Thank you so much!

I tried using a while loop for Function A but it didn't work. I thought the solution might lie in "threading" or "asyncio" but I'm not sure how to use these two libraries.

Comment: Simple way would be to make `a` global and let `Calculate_a` set `a` after calculation.

Comment: Won't the result of Function 2 be the same for 5 hours, while waiting for Function 1 to complete? What's the point of running Function 2 every 5 seconds if it's always the same value?

Comment: Function 2 implements a feature, b can change and is the result of another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two separate processes and a manager to communicate the result of the calculation of `a` from the first to the second process. That way, the 2nd process continuously outputs data, using the last know value for `a`. As soon as `a` gets updated in the 1st process, the 2nd process uses the new value as well.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def calc_a(x, y, z, z, manager_namespace):
    # calculate a
    manager_namespace.a = new_a

def sum_ab(manager_namespace, b):
    s = manager_namespace.a + b
    print(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    global_ns = manager.Namespace()
    global_ns.x = 0
    p1 = Process(target=calc_a, args=(x, y, z, t, global_ns))
    p1.start()

    p2 = Process(target=sum_ab, args=(global_ns, b))
    p2.start()


    p.join()
```